# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute get_text - Python

Tags: python

intento construir una pequeña aplicación que realice el seguimiento el precio de un artículo en una página web, para ello hago uso de Python. Mi problema es que al ejecutar el código me devuelve el siguiente error :  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute get_text.

Entiendo que no me está devolviendo información alguna, pero no sé cómo solucionarlo.

Con la variable `item` selecciono el nombre del artículo y con la variable `price` el precio, todo ello mediante los `id`

He puesto los id correspondientes a cualquier artículo de la página de ventas online Amazon.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://www.amazon.es/New-Balance-Pursuit-Zapatillas-Running/dp/B07BL2M23B/ref=sr_1_11?fst=as%3Aoff&pf_rd_p=2a5791f9-c743-4197-a129-1ff9f9917eae&pf_rd_r=EDSVS08VR2828TBNQYQ8&qid=1562094142&rnid=5517557031&s=apparel&sr=1-11&th=1&psc=1'

#Get information about the browser.
headers =  {"User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:67.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/67.0'}


#Returns all the data from the website.
page = requests.get(URL, headers = headers)

#Parse all the information for then pull out individual pieces of information.
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

#Find an id in a HTML document.
item = soup.find(id = "productTitle").get_text()
price = soup.find(id = "priceblock_ourprice").get_text()



print(item)
print(price)
```

Comment: Cuando `find()` no encuentra lo que le pides, retorna `None`. En ese caso tratar de hacer `.get_text()` sobre el valor retornado te causa el error que mencionas (que literalmente te está diciendo que un valor de tipo `NonType` no tiene el método `.get_text()`)

Comment: Perfecto, entonces mi duda recae en por qué me devuelve None cuando debería de existir una coincidencia. Gracias de antemano

Comment: La web de amazon españa bloquea las consultas, si lo pruebas con un link de amazon.de por ejemplo te va a funcionar